# Getting documents from MongoDB as objects with PHP?

Tags: php, mongodb

I'm totally new to Mongo, having first used it about a week ago.  I've spent the past few months developing an application which produces complex JSON objects.  The original intent was to store them in Mongo, and the time has come to implement CRUD.

During development I had my app set up to read JSON from a static array in my controller (CodeIgniter 2.1).  This worked just fine; I imported them using Mongo shell, and everything is structured correctly.

Each document is an object; the object has properties which are objects, arrays of objects, and so on.  I'm totally fine with Mongo inserting its _id object into my documents.

But PHP refuses to *return* my documents as objects; it gives me arrays instead.  In fact, every object in the document is returning as an array, at every depth.

**It seems like it should be trivial to prevent this unwanted type conversion behavior, but how?**  I can't find any reference on how to do it.

Also, data beginning at the 7th level of depth (which happens to be [document object].[array].[object].[object].[object].[array].**[object]**) is getting omitted.

Originally we thought this was happening in somewhere in CodeIgniter, ActiveRecord, or the cimongo library, but today I got the same wrong document structure by using the MongoDB extension directly.

The web server is running Debian squeeze, PHP 5.3.3-7+squeeze15, MongoDB PHP extension version 1.2.12.  The host where Mongo is running tells me "MongoDB shell version: 2.4.5" when I log in.

Comment: As I understand conversion happens when you insert from php http://www.php.net/manual/en/mongo.tutorial.insert.php, and MongoCollection::findOne always returns array

Comment: @cske: The two that exist so far were imported via the Mongo shell, not PHP.  PHP is mangling them on the way out.

Comment: think you won't get it with the extension, try https://support.mongolab.com/entries/20433053-Is-there-a-REST-API-for-MongoDB- OR http://www.doctrine-project.org/projects/mongodb-odm.html

Comment: @cske: I'll check those out, thanks.  For now, I'm storing the JSON as a base64 encoded string until this can be worked out.

Comment: Can you provide code samples to build, save to mongodb, and retrieve from mongodb such a document? As @cske mentions, the return from mongodb is an array, not a PHP object. You will have to un-marshal it yourself or use an ODM like Doctrine.

Answer (score -1):

The PHP Driver will always return MongoDB documents as arrays.

This is because PHP arrays can both be associative and numeric, so after inserting an associative array.. you wouldn't want to get back a stdclass object.

We simply cannot differentiate an associative array from a stdclass object, as JSON (and BSON for that matter) do not have an associative array type.

In PHP it isn't particularly common to work with stdclass objects, and I barely have ever seen a stdclass object of arrays or the other way around - its also very cumbersome to work with (remember [SimpleXML](http://php.net/simplexml)?).

When you are saving complex structure (such as your application Models), ODM (Object Document Mappers) systems like [Doctrine](http://www.doctrine-project.org/projects/mongodb-odm.html) will add an additional key to the document as metadata about its structure. Then when retrieving the document they look up this fieldname to understand how the data should be converted back into its original from (e.g. your original Model structure).